Is any planets angular speed roughly constant?
The duration of a sidereal day stays pretty much constant on Earth as far as I know. But I was wondering if that is typical or even always the case. For example, can moons influence it? Or can sidereal days durations change when the rotation around the planets star is very elliptical? (I think that's called "high eccentricity", right?)
The core of a planet cooling down should not change anything due to conservation of angular momentum, right?
Just to clarify: I know that different planets have different sidereal day durations, e.g. from the "sidereal duration period" entry on the Wikipedia articles:

Earth: 23h 56 m 4.100s
Mars: 24h 37m 22.7s
Saturn: 10h 33m 38s - here it says +1m 52s/− 1m 19s
Jupiter: 9h 55 m 30 s
Pluto: 6 d, 9 h, 17 m, 36 s


This might be better suited for the astronomy stack: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Thanks! I didn't know that one

Depends on how close "roughly constant" is.  Yes other bodies can influence the earth's rotation.  The moon has the biggest long-term effect as the oceanic tides it raises helps to couple the rotation of the earth to the orbit of the moon.   This slows down the rotation over centuries.
The surface of the earth also exchanges momentum on short timescales with both the earth's core and with the atmosphere.   Changes in the shape and mass distribution of the crust due to earthquake slips, deformation from glaciers and glacier melting and the relocation of water all can make small contributions to deviations in the rotation period.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/highlights-of-astronomy/article/earth-rotation-variations-from-hours-to-centuries/84497BCD02BEF00B835B7A4DE21C15BE has many details.
The fewer of these influences, the more steady a planetary rotation would be.   A planet with a cooled interior, no atmosphere, no oceans, no moons, and significant distance from any other objects would have greater stability for its rotation.

You wrote that tides caused by the moon slow the rotation of earth down. Are there also (regular) processes that speed it up? (Non-regular would be e.g. impact of a meteorite)

I believe nothing significant for the earth.   For some smaller bodies (asteroids) you can get solar-driven outgassing that lines up in a way to increase the rotation rate.
